# Mini Tetris Winning Configuration

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, puzzle, recursion

So here's the problem:

A winning configuration in the game of Mini-Tetris is a complete tiling of a 2 x n board using only the three shapes shown in Figure 1. By allowing rotations, there can be more configurations to complete the titling. Figure 2 shows some winning configurations to fill 2 x 3 board. Letting Tn denote the number of different winning configurations on a 2 x n board, the first five values are T1 = 1, T2 = 3, T3 = 7, T4 = 17, and T5 = 39. Express Tn in terms of Tn-1, Tn-2, Tn-3, and Tn-4, and compute T6.

Can someone please solve it and explain to me what's going on at each step? Thank you!

I said Tn = Tn-1 + 2Tn-2 and T6 = 73 but apparently that's wrong.

[image]

Comment: Where is the problem from?

Comment: Practice problem from a worksheet on my discrete mathematics class.

Answer (score 1):

Let $U_n$ be the number of ways to cover a $2\times n$ board with one corner square missing.  Clearly
$$U_1=0\ ,\quad U_2=1\ .$$
In the first of your five diagrams, we start the $2\times n$ board with an L-shaped piece at the bottom.  The number of ways to complete the covering is then $U_{n-1}$.  In the fourth, we start with a two-square piece placed vertically; then the one next to it is forced; then there are $T_{n-2}$ ways to complete the covering of the $2\times n$ board.  In fact, the five diagrams show all ways of placing the initial piece.  See if you can use arguments similar to those I have given to show that the total number of ways to cover the board is
$$T_n=U_{n-1}+U_{n-1}+T_{n-2}+T_{n-2}+T_{n-1}\ ,$$
that is,
$$T_n=T_{n-1}+2T_{n-2}+2U_{n-1}\ .\tag{$*$}$$
Starting with a $2\times(n-1)$ board with a bottom corner missing, show similarly that
$$U_{n-1}=U_{n-2}+T_{n-3}\ .\tag{$*{*}$}$$
Now from $(*)$ we get
$$\eqalign{
  2U_{n-1}&=T_n-T_{n-1}-2T_{n-2}\cr
  2U_{n-2}&=T_{n-1}-T_{n-2}-2T_{n-3}\ ;\cr}$$
substitute into $(*{*})$ to eliminate the $U$ terms, and then simplify.

Comment: I think there's an easier way to solve this problem. Don't you think?

Comment: Please let me know how, I would love to see it.

Comment: anyone have a link to other source of this problem ? besides Iowa State oeis . I can't find the work of Bringham 96

Comment: I don't think the solution posted would be for a discrete math class of h.s. level . the problem is much simplified then the one that handles all tetrominos or tetris pieces

Comment: David I dont see how u got the Tn-3 in **

Comment: @Randin Starting with a $2\times(n-1)$ board with a bottom corner missing, the bottom square can be filled in with (i) a $2\times1$ block; this leaves a $2\times(n-2)$ board with a bottom corner missing, which can be completed in $U_{n-2}$ ways; or (ii) an L-shaped block; this leaves a $2\times(n-3)$ board, which can be completed in $T_{n-3}$ ways.

Comment: can u gmail me this ?

Comment: n-1 pieces or squares?

Comment: can u attach a diagram please

Comment: Ah i think your L would be rotated to the left clockwise in your Tn-3 configuration right ? because the bottom LEFT corner in one case and if the board started with a bottom right corner it would again be Tn-3 since the n is SQUARES , am i right ?

Comment: Sorry, not good at posting diagrams.  I think your last comment is right.

Comment: I think I get it after a somewhat lengthy process that nearly always happens in math. the Tn-3 is when an L shaped piece 'caps off' the 2 x (n-1) board. the L fills the empty square then levels of the board. for the other case a domino falls in that spot we end up with another 'U board', one that as you defined has an empty square at bottom . That would be completed in Un-2 ways .