# Well ordering principle for mini tetris

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, well-orders

Prove using well ordering principle that for all $n\ge 0$, the number $T_n$ of tilings of a $n  \times 2$ tetris board is :  $\frac{3^{n+1} + (-1)^{n}}{4}$

I am using MIT OCW to learn this on my own.

My approach: Let there be a non empty set S with a lowest number m not satisfying the above equation. $m>0$ because $n=0$ clearly satisfies the above equation. Therefore all numbers smaller than m will satisfy the above equation. Therefore m-1 will satisfy. Then I substitute m-1 in the above equation. But after doing that I get no useful result.

What should I be doing instead ?

Comment: Can you explain what a tiling of an $n\times2$ tetris board is, please?

Comment: A proof using the well-ordering principle is almost the same as a proof using induction.  You want to prove that the "smallest counterexample" isn't really a counterexample at all.  So, if you can establish a formula for $T_n$ is term of the values $T_k$ where $k<n$, then you can substitute the given expression for $T_n$ into it.  Look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1235055/mini-tetris-winning-configuration

Answer (score 1):

With the information provided alone, one cannot solve this problem. You have to add which tiles are available. As I have seen this problem before [here at page 41](https://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.042/spring18/mcs.pdf), the tiling could be used to derive the following:

$T_{n}=2 \cdot T_{n-1} + 3\cdot T _{n-2}$.

Without this information, you cannot prove anything.

Let $P(n)$ be the statement that $T_{n}=2 \cdot T_{n-1} + 3\cdot T _{n-2}$

Now let $C$ be the set of counterexamples where $P(n)$ does not hold.

By WOP, there is a least element $m$ in $C$.

Now take $P(m-1) + P(m-2) = 2 \cdot \frac{3^{m-1+1} + (-1)^{m-1}}{4} + 3 \cdot\frac{3^{m-2+1} + (-1)^{m-2}}{4}$

Simplifying and rearranging the terms, you will get

$P(m-1) + P(m-2) = \frac{3^{m} + (-1)^{m}}{4}$ which shows that $P(n)$ holds for $m$ which is a contradiction to our original assumption.